# How to adjust bootstrap carousel arrows height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This happened when I changed the height of the .well class:

[image]

I tried to modify the height for the controls, the .carousel-inner and also the height of the carousel itself. All of these still yield the same results. I figure if I was able to change the background color of the carousel-control, I would be able to modify the height on the same elements. May I know which class to can be modified to change this?

```
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="prev" style="background: #f8f8f8 !important">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="next" style="background: #f8f8f8 !important">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
```

Comment: are you able to provide us with a link to see the actual website?

Comment: Hi I am currently testing my code on localhost, so as of now I have yet to host it on a web hosting site

Comment: the picture is really confusing

Comment: Oh my bad, I'll edit the image and show the full carousel.
Edit: I've edited the image, apologies for the confusion

Comment: if you are using chrome, and right click on the arrow and inspect, you should be able to see the exact class you need to modify.

Comment: I have already checked which are the possible class needed to modify, and have mentioned my testings and how it didn't work. In the developer tools(the inspect element, I presume), and the classes are the carousel control.

Comment: Can you reproduce that section of your code on a jsfiddle? It wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Based on the markup, this is rather Bootstrap 3, not Bootstrap 4, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the selectors you are trying to find:

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left:before,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

So fitted into a Bootstrap 3 environment (as based on OP's markup this is BS 3, not 4) here is the [example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/YEombB).